# AngularJS: Changing object does not update field but changing string directly does

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I feel like this is something trivial, but I've been stuck for awhile.

I have an object `user`, set in the directive UserSettings. The directive's element contains a button with html `{{user.name}}` to open a model for user settings. When the page loads `user.name` is set.

The user settings form in the modal is contained by a controller called UserSettingsForm. I've been trying to debug the controller and I'm confused by the behavior I'm seeing.

```
console.log @$scope.user # debug to show user object is there
@$scope.test = angular.copy(@$scope.user) # set test equal to a copy of user
@$scope.test.name = 'wowee' # change test object's 'name' property
@$scope.user = angular.copy(@$scope.test) # set user back to test
console.log @$scope.test # test is changed
console.log @$scope.user # user is equivalent to test
```

The above debugging works as expected, but the unexpected part (for me, at least) is the fact that `{{user.name}}` in the nav bar is not being updated. But when I do `@$scope.user.name = @$scope.test.name` the `{{user.name}}` field in the HTML is updated.

I am admittedly an angular noob (even though this is probably a JavaScript concept), but the logic I'm having trouble with doesn't make sense to me and I would be very appreciative if someone could clear it up for me, and maybe even give me a push in the right direction as far as properly updating the `user` object to equal the `test` object. `test` will eventually be an instance of the user settings form and only when the data is saved successfully will that instance be saved as `user`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular is still watching the previous reference, even after you do the change.

If you use:

```
angular.copy(source, destination)
```

It will deleted all of the previous properties and replace them with the source properties.

Here's the updated example for your case:

```
angular.copy($scope.test, $scope.user)
```

That statement should solve the issue.